# AlarmManager's repeating alarm is being run only once

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm setting my repating alarm with `startInMillis=1383240650` (Thu, 24 Oct 2013 17:30:50 GMT) and it runs on time as expected but only once, it is not being repeated ever again. My intention was to run it in seven day interval, so the next occurance should took place in (Thu, 31 Oct 2013 17:30:50 GMT) but it didn't.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, randomInt, startIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startInMillis, (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You should not be using `RTC_WAKEUP` with a `getService()` `PendingIntent`. You need to use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, coupled with either my `WakefulIntentService`, the Android Support package's `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, or your own equivalent. Beyond that, use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** after the first event to examine when it is scheduled to run next.

Comment: Okay I'll test it, but in this case why is the alarm works once even if device is asleep? Moreover it works also if interval time is short (let's say 15 minutes).

Comment: Using a `getService()` `PendingIntent` is unreliable. It will work sometimes and not others. `_WAKEUP` only guarantees that `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` will be awake -- anything else, all bets are off.